# How to install fwbuilder on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, command-line

I'm trying install fwbuilder, but i get error that told me:

Summary:

```
Running as user : root
Firewall name : mti
Installer uses user name : fwadmin
Management address : 192.168.1.6
Platform : iptables
Host OS : linux24
Loading configuration from file /home/amr/fwbuilder/repo/mti.fwb
```

Installation plan:
Copy file:

```
/home/amr/fwbuilder/repo/mti.fw --> /etc/fw/mti.fw
```

Run script:

```
echo '--**--**--'; chmod +x /etc/fw/mti.fw; sudo -S /etc/fw/mti.fw && echo 'Policy activated'
Copying /home/amr/fwbuilder/repo/mti.fw -> 192.168.1.6:/etc/fw/mti.fw
Running command '/usr/bin/fwbuilder -Y scp -o ConnectTimeout=30 -P 2222  ~/.ssh/identity -q /home/amr/fwbuilder/repo/mti.fw fwadmin@192.168.1.6:/etc/fw/mti.fw'
Firewall Builder GUI 5.1.0.3599
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.6 port 2222: Connection refused
lost connection
SSH session terminated, exit status: 1
Firewall policy installation failed
```

How do I stop this error?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.6 port 2222: Connection refused
```

The host you are trying to connect(192.168.1.6) either don't have SSH installed, it is stopped or is listening in a different port than 2222.

So first check if the machine with that IP has SSH installed. In Ubuntu SSH (to accept connections) is provided by `openssh-server`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Then check it is running:

```
$ service ssh status
ssh start/running, process XXXXXX
```

If it is stopped:

```
$ sudo service ssh start
```

Also usually SSH listens on port 22 and not 2222 as your script is trying to use. So check if that script has some switch to define a different port.